# SQL Query to produce email list based on specific requirements

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I can't seem to figure out the best way to do this. Logic: Think of Facebook for this example. If I comment on a post, anyone who is following that post should get an email, but not me as it was my initial comment. I should however receive notification when others comment on a post that I'm following.

> PostA: I'm following 
>  PostB: I'm following
>  PostA: I posted a comment
>   PostB: Someone else posted a comment

I should get an email about PostB but not PostA.

Next...

```
PostB: I posted a comment.
```

I should not get a notification but the other person should.

---

I'm using a personalized email scheduler and here is the work-flow:

1. I set a run condition.
2. I set the recipients list using SQL query.
3. I create personalized inserts for the email (I.e. new comments on a post you're following).

I have 3 tables for this example:

1. PostFollowers (UserID, Email, PostID)
2. Post (PostID, Message, Notification_Sent <- BIT)
3. PostComments (CommentID, UserID, Comment, Notification_Sent <- BIT)

---

**Step1**: Set a run condition

```
SELECT * FROM PostComments WHERE Notification_Sent = 0
```

If values are returned the application will execute the campaign.

**Step2**: Select the Recipients

```
SELECT 
     a.Email
    ,a.PostID

     FROM PostFollowers
     INNER JOIN PostComments b on a.PostID = b.PostID
     WHERE b.Notification_Sent = 0
```

So my above recipients query includes any person who is following a post that currently have comments that haven't been sent notifications yet.

What would be the best way to adjust my query so that the recipients are ONLY those who are following a post, but any related comment was not their own. They should only get an email if comments exist that were not created by themselves. Say some time goes by and I've posted 10 comments on one post. An email should go out to any OTHER person who is following. Then someone comes along and posts a comment. I should now get an email.

I'm probably over-thinking this. Perhaps a count that subtracts my comments and is in the WHERE clause?

Thank you and I'm a bit tired... hope my question was clear.

Comment: There is no link between PostComments and UserId who commented this comment. Add Column UserId to PostComments. Then you must add condition to join: on a.PostID = b.PostID and a.UserId != b.UserId

Comment: This was an oversight on my part when posting the question. I apologize. That column does in fact exist. I'm super paranoid to send out the emails as I'm afraid I'll mess something up.

Comment: Looks like I've missed the obvious based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NoGotnu has already mentioned the below query should do the work

```
SELECT 
     pf.Email
    ,pf.PostID
FROM 
     PostFollowers pf
INNER JOIN 
     PostComments pc ON 
     pf.PostID = pc.PostID
WHERE 
         pc.Notification_Sent = 0 
     AND pf.UserID != pc.UserID
```